# Why does my delete all button need to be double clicked to work?

Tags: javascript

So, I was adding a delete all button and it works, the only problem is that it needs to be double clicked just to make it work.

may I ask what's wrong? thank you :)

I added the codes that were used to create the button here:

```
<body>
<!--for everything in the navigation part including the add favorite bar-->
<div class="topnav">

    <div class="addFave">
        <!--the text bar-->
        <input type="text" name="enter" class="enter" value="" id="added"  placeholder= "Add Favorites"/>
        <!--the enter button-->
        <input type="button" value="Enter" id = "addIt" OnClick="adding()" />
        <!--for the script of the add favorite bar to add its functions-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var faves = [];

            var y = document.getElementById("added");
                function adding() {
                    faves.push(y.value);
                    document.getElementById("faveLists").innerHTML = faves;
                }
            var input = document.getElementById("added");
                input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                    document.getElementById("addIt").click();
                }
            }); 
        </script>
    </div>
</div>


<br />

<div class="buttons">
    <button onclick="eradicateFaves()">Remove All Favorite</button>


    <script>
-coding to remove all the favorites on the list-->
        function eradicateFaves(){
            document.getElementById("faveLists").innerHTML = faves;
                while(faves.length > 0){                   
                faves.shift();
            }
        }    

    </script>
</div>
<p id = "faveLists"></p>
```

Comment: Please add all of your HTML code, as well as the rest of your JavaScript code. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: alright, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(faves.length > 0){                   
    faves.shift();
}
```

Why not just `faves = []` to empty it? And shouldn't you empty the list *before* assigning it? That's why you need two clicks; first time re-assigns current list then empties it, and second time assigns the empty list then does nothing more as it is already empty. So, try this:

```
function eradicateFaves(){
    faves = [];
    document.getElementById("faveLists").innerHTML = faves;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say "delete all" I assume you mean reset the `faves` array back to `[]`. Well why not just do this:

```
function eradicateFaves() {
    faces = [];
    document.getElementById("faveLists").innerHTML = faves;
}
```

The reason it wasn't working earlier was because [`Array.prototype.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) only removes the first element of the array. According to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift):

> The `shift()` method removes the first element from an array and returns that removed element. This method changes the length of the array.

Comment: `shift()` was in a `while` loop, so it eventually shifted each element off the list.